# Target specific element after if.length function on group of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I am extremely close just need the last bit on how to integrate $(this) into my function.

I am trying to see if parentDiv contains childDiv and then remove border on said parentDiv (all defined by classes).

So far I have :

```js
$(function() {
  var parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
  var childDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("class2");

  if ($(childDiv, parentDiv).length) {
    $(parentDiv).addClass("noborder");
  }

});
```

Imagine the **HTML** as follows, the goal is that on the second **class1** it reads: class="class1 noborder" because the class1 contains a class2

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="class2"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
```

Currently I am obviously replacing all parentDiv's but I want to target the specific one that the **if test** is being done on, any help appreciated

Comment: Could you please include your html code?

Comment: I tried adding $(this) into the if test but I feel I need to wrap the if test into another function where I establish $(this) off parentDiv and use that but I am not sure how to pursue that.

Comment: Added to main post, I am on a different machine to post this, but imagine the html as written above - simplified

Comment: Not sure I understand what it is you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Do you want to add the class `noborder` if a `class1` has a `class2` ?

Comment: Trying to have class="class1 noborder" on the second div - if class1 contains class2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't mind using jQuery, you can use [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) function to achieve that

```js
$(function(){
  $(".class1").has(".class2").addClass('noborder');
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="class2"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [`has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```js
$('.class1:has(.class2)').addClass('border');


// add content for demo
$('.class1').children().text(function(){
  return $(this).attr('class')
})
```

```css
.border{border: 1px solid green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="bla"></div>  
  <div class="class2"></div>  
  <div class="bla"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(jQuery('#class1').find('.class2').length !== 0){
   jQuery('#class1').addClass("noborder");
}
```

This should work.